# Concatenate variable and sting in graphql query

Tags: reactjs, graphql-js

I'm trying to add `my/custom/path/`to the `$path` variable but have no idea on how to do this. Already looked at the documentation but couldn't find anything that mentions this.

```
export const postQuery = graphql`
    query BlogPostByPath($path: String!) {
        markdownRemark(frontmatter: { path: { eq: $path } }) {
            html
            frontmatter {
                path
                title
                description
                keywords
            }
        }
    }
`;
```

Comment: Can you show the resolve function of `markdownRemark`? First time seeing such nested argument passing. Are you using Apollo as GraphQl client?

Comment: @ArupRakshit I'm using gatsby and the plugin called `gatsby-transformer-remark` so it might look different. I'm not sure what else I can provide to help you :/

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Gatsby, try:

```
graphql(`<your_query_with_variable>`, { variable: <value_of_variable> })
```

Source: [Passing a string to GraphQL queries argument.](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/4050)